# Spring mvc test case with string in request header and multipart file as a request parameter for a post request

Tags: spring-mvc-test

```
@Controller
 @PostMapping("/hello/{studentName}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> method1(

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload/{studentName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveAuto(
            @PathVariable(value = "name") String name,` `
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile myFile) {
          }
    }
```

Hi, I am new to unit test. can anyone please help me for writing test case using mockmvcbuilderrequest..
I tried this but getting 404
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/hello/{zoneName}","com.example")
.file(file).accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))

Comment: the error is in the uri, "hello/" is sent and it should be "upload/".

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. Change the rest path and put: "/hello/{studentName}", in this way the test will work as you have explained.
2. Leave the rest path "/upload/{studentName}" and change the uri in the test from "/hello/{studentName}" to "/upload/{studentName}".

***I leave the way to execute the test, with the correction.***

```
mockMvc.perform(
    MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/upload/{studentName}","Anu Shree") 
        .file(file)
        .accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
)
```

I hope it helps